# Partition column in hive external table from spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Creating external table with partitions from spark

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode


 val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("splitInput").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

val sparkDf = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("input/candidate/event=ABCD/CandidateScheduleData_3007_2018.csv")

var newDf = sparkDf 
for(col <- sparkDf.columns){    newDf = newDf.withColumnRenamed(col,col.replaceAll("\\s", "_"))  }

newDf.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("path","/output/candidate/event=ABCD/").partitionBy("CenterCode","ExamDate").saveAsTable("abc.candidatelist")
```

Everything works fine except the partition column `ExamDate` format created as

```
 ExamDate=30%2F07%2F2018 instead of ExamDate=30-07-2018
```

How to replace`%2F` with `-` in ExamDate format.

Answer (score 0):

`%2F` is percent encoded `/`. This means that data is exactly in `30/07/2018` format. You can either:

- Parse it `to_date` using specified format.
- Manually format columns with required format.